# starting server with nohup and redirecting input, output

Tags: bash, io-redirection, nohup

I have a init.d script that starts a python socket server.  Because I want this to run as a daemon, I use nohup to start it.  I also want to redirect stdout and stderr to a log file.  My problem is that I am also trying to capture the PID of the process to save to a file, which I can't seem to do.

```
# Start server
echo "Starting server."
nohup ${PROGDIR}/${PROGNAME} -l $IPADDR >>${LOGDIR}/${OUTLOG} 2>>${LOGDIR}/${OUTLOG} </dev/null &
PID=$!
```

This was able to capture the PID, but redirection did not work. (Was I redirecting nohup rather than the program?)

Next I tried something like:

```
nohup /bin/bash -c '...'
```

But I lost the PID.  At this point, I seemed to be getting the PID of `nohup /bin/bash -c`.  As I am not very familiar with shell scripts, I thought I would ask for help before I shoot myself in the foot.

So my question is, how can I capture the PID and redirect the server output to the logfile?  I am on a debian (raspberry pi) and am writing an init script using rc-update.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Debian variant, you have `start-stop-daemon` available, which does all this for you in a much cleaner way.  In particular:

```
start-stop-daemon --make-pidfile --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --background \
    --no-close --exec "${PROGDIR}/${PROGNAME}" --start -- -l "$IPADDR" \
    >> "${LOGDIR}/${OUTLOG}" 2>> "${LOGDIR}/${OUTLOG}" </dev/null
```

should be pretty close to what you want.  It puts the PID in a file instead of into a variable, but you can of course read it back out into a variable easily.

Comment: Looks like `--no-close` is not always available